# Refreshing static instances across multiple worker process

Tags: iis-7.5, web-garden

We recently experimented with running IIS (7.5) in web garden mode (i.e. 2 (or more) worker processes.

We use out of process state (state server) and are looking at App Fabric for out of process cache management, so no issues there.

We currently use a static singleton for our location hierarchy, when new locations are added, the singleton is refreshed.

With multiple worker processes only the instance in the current instance is refreshed, the other instances are out of synch.

How might we synchronize them? One option might be to recycle the app pool, causing all worker processes to refresh, and re-instantiate their caches / statics, but this seems like overkill.